# Saddle suggestions for broken pelvis

Tags: racing, saddle, injury, gel-saddle

I am a female getting into serious cycling, and will be riding in a 200 kms charity race (over 2 days) in June 2017, as well as beginning to compete.

In 2013, I broke my pelvis in 3 places. I broke both ischial tuberosity bones, though I broke them at the "top" of each round ring, not the bottom. I also broke the sacrum bone right next to the right side of my spine (2mm) away.

I have healed perfectly fine, and have no pain, except when I am cycling long distances. I start to get sore at 50 km, and it gets worse as the distance increases. It is the ischial tuberosities that get sore, not the sacrum bone.

I will not allow this to get in the way of cycling. There is a way to overcome this, and I will find it.

I need to find a saddle that will take some of the pressure off my ishial tuberosity bones, and I am looking for suggestions.

I live in Toronto, Canada, if that helps.

Please send me suggestions or ideas, so that I can kick some butt on my races, without my bones kicking my butt.

Comment: Have you tried calling a doctor? Or using a recumbent?

Comment: I'd suggest consulting a qualified medical-type person.  Even a trained bike-fitter will have a hard time working out your hip problems.

Comment: Do you ride with clipless pedals?  Do you get out of the saddle periodically?   Are you stuck to your normal diamond-frame bike or would you consider moving to another frame style?

Comment: For all of us, our choice of saddle is very personal - there are many different saddles out there, and you just hope to find one that feels comfortable. Often, unfortunately, it is a case of trial and error. I'm not sure that the fact that you once broke your pelvis comes into it.

Comment: Hey Batman, I don't want to use a recumbent, as I will be competing in road cycling, so I have to ride what is approved as a competition bike.

Comment: The same goes ofr getting out of the saddle...it will slow me down too much in a road race.  For now, I am using my full suspension mountain bike ( I bought it as part of my physiotherapy, as I broke my right leg in the same accident that I broke my pelvis in, and I needed the suspension of the bike to take the hits more than my pelvis). I have just recently hooked my mountain bike up to a Minoura RDA 80 trainer for the winter months. I do 2 hours each day at the moment, but am sore by the end.

Comment: I am very determined however, and I am also learning some things from a guy that has been competing for 25 years. I am absolutely serious when I say that I will be competing. If you knew the strength of my stubborn determination, and dedication once I make up my mind, you would understand. I will likely try going to a trained bike fitter, but I wondered if there was a brand or style that I should start to consider more closely, given my past pelvis issues. I appreciate all your comments and suggestions!

Comment: You may try looking into a noseless saddle.  Some of the designs I have seen actually have cutouts or the sit bones in particular.  I am not a big fan of them myself, but they may hopefully be an alternative for you.  You may also looking into an alternative fit of some sort.  Perhaps a more aggressive position that placed more weight on your hands (or other slightly non-traditional fitting) would be of benefit.

Comment: @SuspendedUser, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks suspended user! The idea of a seat with cutouts for the sit bones may be exactly what I need. Do you have any brand names that you could suggest?

Comment: I don't because I only ever "used" one briefly (five minute ride on a mate's bike).  However, a search for "noseless bicycle saddle" should give you a good place to start.

Comment: I can't interpret your description of your injuries very well, but I'll chime in that there are a number of "oddball" saddle designs.  Probably there is some web site somewhere where they are all reviewed.

Comment: Jesse, you don't say anything about the seat you currently use. Is it padded? Designed for women? What different seats have you tried? I question the whole idea that you need a special seat. Since you are "just getting into cycling" I suspect that the muscles in your rear just need time to develop. Two hours is about the point they often tire for many non cyclists.

Comment: Andy256. I have thought of the fact that my mucsles need time, but I am already very fit. Before cycling training started, I was doing 8 kms a day on a treadmill, and doing full body strength training. I have swapped the treadmill for my bike, and do two hours a day on that as well as the strength training. I do realize that when most people say they are getting into cycling, they are pretty out of shape, but that is not the case here. My career is also very physical. My current saddle is a cheap one that came with my mountain bike. I will tough this saddle out until I find a better one.

Comment: My mountain bike is not the bike I will be competing with...I will be doing road bike racing. I need to buy a new bike for the road bike racing, but my mountain bike works with the cycling trainer that I have, so it will do for the winter. I will be taking everyone's advice and looking into noseless saddles, and ones that are hollowed out where my sit bones touch the saddle. That way, I can try out a new saddle while I train over the winter months, and can put that new saddle on whatever new competition road bike I get.

Comment: ISM is one brand that makes noseless saddles, it may be worth shooting them an email with this same question, Hobson easy seat is another, it's more like two small saddles that are not connected, that way each "cheek" moves independently as you peddle.

Answer (score 6):

You may try looking into a noseless saddle. Some of the designs I have seen actually have cutouts or the sit bones in particular. Many people are dismissive of them (myself somewhat included), but they may hopefully be an alternative for you. Here is a [completely random blog entry](http://www.thebirdwheel.com/noseless-saddles-tested-updated) on the interwebz comparing several. There appears to be a large range of manufacturing quality as well as actual design effort, so I would resarch rather carefully before purchasing.

I would also strongly look into an alternative fit of some sort. Perhaps a more aggressive position that placed more weight on your hands (or other slightly non-traditional fitting) would be of benefit.  Professional fittings should always be looked at as a place to start.  Especially with past injuries or other less stereotypical anatomy, minor or major adjustments should be expected.  In the end it may not be one thing, but a combination of things (including perhaps time) that help things along for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a saddle that takes pressure off your sit bones (ischial tuberosities), this design is probably appropriate:

[image: ISM Adamo Prologue]

There may be others brands that use a similar design, but I think ISM is the best known.

The idea is that most of your weight is supported on the frontal prongs, rather than the flat area at the back.  They have a gap in the middle to avoid putting pressure on your perineum.  For this reason they're especially popular among time triallists and triathletes because they allow you to rotate your pelvis forward more comfortably.

They feel quite different to conventional saddles, mostly because of the extra width at the front, and will probably take some getting used to.

The image came from [this review](http://www.slowtwitch.com/Products/Saddles/ISM_Long_Term_Test_2890.html).